# Maven Grails Project won't run (using GGTS)

Tags: maven, grails, ggts

I imported a project to the Groovy/Grails Tool Suite and when I run my project on and click "Run As: Run on Server" I get a 404 error.

Additionally, a separate issue is the debug not seeing the source correctly when stopped at a breakpoint when running via maven run config (mvn grails:run-app).

This question may be under descriptive - if you need any additional details to answer the question let me know.